# In Drupal 6 how to get two dates from url and filter content in views based on date range?

Tags: views

I have one view where i am displaying contents. I want to pass 2 dates from view url, which will be content post dates. I want to know how to get dates from url and filter content between the date range.

[image]

Comment: I am not sure but try https://www.drupal.org/project/views_daterange.

Comment: Or may be this should work : http://ericlondon.com/2008/12/11/drupal-6-passing-date-ranges-into-a-view-as-arguments.html.